# How to declare a primary key in mongodb? create index wihout know the value of it

Tags: mongodb

Hi I need to create a primary key.

If I insert `{ "name":"test1", "age":10}`
and then `{ "name":"test1", "age":20}`.

if I need that name be a primary key I need to create an index:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "name": "test1" }, { unique: true } )
```

But I think thats not solve the problem, if I insert 1000 names, after every insert,I need to create an index? Are there any better solution?

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/

Comment: yeah, I put an example....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I insert 1000 names, after every insert,I need to create an index?

No. You run `createIndex` only once.

**Edit:**
Besides that, your are creating the index the wrong way. Sorry, I just noticed that after your comment in this answer.

The correct sintax for unique index creation is:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "field_name": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

The value after `"field_name":` is not the value of the field itself, but the direction of the index. It can be:

* **1**: ascending

* **-1**: descending

So, in your case, you will do the following to create a unique index with names in ascending order:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "name": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

That said, you must be aware of the following:

1. The unique index creation will fail if you already have duplicate content in the field `name`. So, the best time to create the index is before you add documents to the collection.
2. If you insert documents that don't contain the field `name`, for the first one, a field `"name": null` will be automatically created. The next document without that field will fail to be inserted because of the pre-existence of a document with `"name": null`.

More details [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/)

Comment: I dont understand, How can I create a unique index, if its necesary to pass a name or a number to that index? and every row has a diferent value.

Comment: if I create and index, its only with one value, but i need a index not for a value but for a colum or key in this case.  I need a Key to be unique, not that key = 1 be unique, or key = 2 be unique

Comment: Sorry, @Victor . I only noticed you were creating the index the wrong way after your comments above. I updated my answer. Hope it helps :)